# Hard reload of a FastAPI app page calls my endpoint twice and gives a strange result

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app that worked fine until now. Here is the main router:

```
@router.get('/{inst_name}')
def chart(request: Request, inst_name: str):
    # Initializing an instance of class 'LiveData'
    lv = tse.LiveData(inst_name, 1)

    data = lv.get_data_for_charts('1min')
    return templates.TemplateResponse('chart.html',
                                      {
                                          'request': request,
                                          'title': inst_name,
                                          'data': data
                                       })
```

Today I changed Javascript code that renders `chart.html` and tried to re-run the app. No matter how much I refreshed the page, I could not see the changes made. So, I decided to do a hard reload on the page, but I got a strange result. The router function was run twice ; the first one did everything as I expected, and the second one failed on the assertion check in the class initialization. Here is the `__init__` method of the class:

```
def __init__(self, inst, avg_volume: int):
    print('inst name:', inst)

    self._inst_name = inst
    inst_id = AllInstCodes().get_inst_id_by_name(inst)
    assert inst_id is not None, 'Invalid instrument name.'
```

I put a `print` statement inside above method to see what causes the assertion to fail. The `inst` parameter in the second initialization of the class is `favicon.ico` !!!

**Why the router method runs twice and where does `favicon.ico` come from?**

Comment: Your router's pattern (`'/{inst_name}'`) catches the `/favicon.ico` as well, that's why you're hitting on that function twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GET /favicon.ico` request is a request your browser makes to retrieve the site's icon that gets shown on the tab in your browser (or in your bookmarks, etc.)

You can ignore this error; it's a request your browser makes in the background and unless you do something very specific with it (i.e. change internal state, etc.) it shouldn't affect anything. You can create an explicit endpoint for it if you want to handle it properly and return a 404 error instead.

The reason why the endpoint runs twice is that there are two requests - your own and the browser's request for `favicon.ico`.

Most common REST API designs uses the resource group name as the initial part of the path to avoid conflicts with other groups that gets added later, so you'd have:

```py
@router.get('/instruments/{inst_name}')
```

instead. This will automagically give a 404 error when anyone attempts to request an undefined path.

Comment: thanks for your perfect answer. I forgot to mention that I have a simple end point that handles 'favicon.ico' request. I wonder why it is never called in my code. However, if I use your workaround it is called on hard reloads. BTW, I have another question: Why do I need a hard reload after changing my JS code? I didn't have any issues before, but now every minor change needs a hard reload. Is there any caching system while running the application on a local host? If it is so, I can't find any in my browser's developer tools.

Comment: @Babak, the endpoint handling `favicon.ico` was never called because the catch-all `@router.get('/{inst_name}')` route matched `/faviocon.ico` first. Note the line in the answer about avoiding path conflicts.

Comment: If the javascript file is external from the page itself the browser will often cache the request; exactly which headers the file is served with will determine how aggressive that cache is in the browser. It'll also depend on how your application is structured.